Some trash data written on my compressed files ( My own algorithm )
This is my program to compress data (it is free but has copyright for commercial usage) . This program suppose to read a file as data-number and find a huge nth root of file (depending on file size) and write as root to exponent and also find the remain numbers and write it to the file for compression (for decompression, it does the reverse). But this code I wrote, writes excessive useless and even weird data in them :

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <gmp.h>
    
int main(void)
{
    
        FILE * fr, * fw;
        char input[201];
        char output[201];
        unsigned long int size = 0;
        unsigned long int rt;
        unsigned char ch[5] = {112,111,119,101,114};
        unsigned char plus[4]={112,108,117,115};
    
    
        printf("Enter filename : ");
        char * r1;
        r1 = fgets(input, 200, stdin);
        input[strcspn(input, "\r\n")] = 0;
        printf("%s\n", r1);
        fr = fopen(input, "rb");
    
    if (fr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during opening of file %s\n", input);
        perror("");
        return 1;
    }
    
        fseek(fr, 0L, SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(fr);
        fseek(fr, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    
    if (size == -1)
    {
    
        fprintf(stderr, "Size doesn't match\n'");
        perror("");
        return 1;
    
    }
    
    if ( size > SIZE_MAX)
    {
    
        fprintf(stderr, "The size of file is greater than acceptable\n");
        perror("");
        return 1;
    
    }
    
        unsigned char * buf = NULL;
        buf = malloc((size_t)size);
    if(buf == NULL)
    {
    
        fprintf(stderr, "Buffer failure\n");
        perror("");
        return 1;
    
    }
    
        int r2;
        r2 = fread(buf, size, 1, fr);
        printf("%d\n", r2);
    if (ferror(fr))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during reading from file %s\n", input);
        perror("");
        fclose(fr);
        return 1;
    }
        fclose(fr);
        fr = NULL;
    
        mpz_t x;
        mpz_init(x);
        mpz_t y;
        mpz_init(y);
    
        mpz_import(x, size, 1, (size_t)1u, 0, 0, buf);
    
    if (size<=15)
        rt = 1;
    else if((size>15)&&(size<=100))
        rt = 9;
    else if((size>100)&&(size<=1000))
        rt = 99;
    else if((size>1000)&&(size<=10000))
        rt = 999;
    else if((size>10000)&&(size<=100000))
        rt = 9999;
    else if((size>100000)&&(size<=1000000))
        rt = 99999;
    else if((size>1000000)&&(size<=10000000))
        rt = 999999;
    else if((size>10000000)&&(size<=100000000))
        rt = 9999999;
    else
        rt = 99999999;
    
    
        mpz_root (y, x, rt);
        mpz_t a;
        mpz_init(a);
        mpz_t b;
        mpz_init(b);
    
        mpz_rootrem (a, b, y, rt);
    
        int rootnum = 0;
        unsigned long int num = rt;
    
    do
    {
    
        num = num/10;
        ++rootnum;
    
    }while(num != 0);
    
        printf("\nEnter compressed filename : ");
        char * r3;
        r3 = fgets(output, 200, stdin);
        output[strcspn(output, "\r\n")] = 0;
        printf("%s\n", r3);
    
    
        memset (buf, 0u, size);
    
        mpz_export(buf, NULL, 1, (size_t)1u, 0, 0, y);
    
        fw = fopen(output, "wb");
    if (fw == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during opening of file %s\n", output);
        perror("");
        return 1;
    }
    
        int w;
        w = fwrite(buf, mpz_sizeinbase(y, 10), 1, fw);
        printf("%d\n", w);
    
    if (ferror(fw)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during writing to file %s\n", output);
        perror("");
        fclose(fw);
        return 1;
    }
    
        fclose(fw);
    
        fw = fopen(output, "ab");
    if(fw == NULL)
    {
        printf("File can't be written\n'");
        return 1;
    }
    if(ferror(fw))
    {
    
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during writing to file %s\n", output);
        perror("");
        fclose(fw);
        return 1;
        
    }
        int w2;
        w2 = fwrite(ch, 5, 1, fw);
        printf("%d\n", w2);
    
        fclose(fw);
    
        fw = fopen(output, "ab");
    if(fw == NULL)
    {
        printf("File can't be written\n'");
        return 1;
    }
    if(ferror(fw))
    {
    
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during writing to file %s\n", output);
        perror("");
        fclose(fw);
        return 1;
        
    }
        int w3;
        w3 = fwrite(&rt, rootnum, 1, fw);
        printf("%d\n", w3);
    
        fclose(fw);
    
        fw = fopen(output, "ab");
    
    if(fw == NULL)
    {
        printf("File can't be written\n'");
        return 1;
    }
    if(ferror(fw))
    {
    
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during writing to file %s\n", output);
        perror("");
        fclose(fw);
        return 1;
        
    }
        int w4;
        w4 = fwrite(plus, 4, 1, fw);
        printf("%d\n", w4);
    
        fclose(fw);
    
        fw = fopen(output, "ab");
    if(fw == NULL)
    {
        printf("File can't be written\n'");
        return 1;
    }
    if(ferror(fw))
    {
    
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during writing to file %s\n", output);
        perror("");
        fclose(fw);
        return 1;
        
    }
    
        int w5;
        w5 = fwrite(b, mpz_sizeinbase(b, 10), 1, fw);
        printf("%d\n", w5);
    
        fclose(fw);
    
        free(buf);
        mpz_clear(x);
        mpz_clear(y);
        mpz_clear(a);
        mpz_clear(b);
    
    return 0;
    
}


I wrote minimal code and everyone said I must check every reading and writing functions . This is the whole program ...
This is a file compressed from Alizee J'en Ai Marre music video on YouTube :
Hex Screenshot - Zoom It
You see two 01 s
This is another file compressed from Mike Oldfield Secrets and Far Above The Clouds from YouTube :
Hex Screenshot - Zoom It
You see two 02 s and two 01 s
This is Terminator 2 : The Judgement Day mkv file and worse than the 2 former files, it has two 0E and filename and pluspower in it :
Hex Screenshot - Zoom it
I'm on Debian 12.8 and compiled GMP 6.3.0
These are not acceptable and reasonable. Is there any GMP pro to say why this trash data is written in the files ?
The code edited as demanded

if (size == -1) - this can never happen. Moreover, it is a common bug to compare signed with unsigned and is leading to very unexpected results. Other than that, your code is poorly indented and could use a lot of refactoring, starting from variable naming and simplifying the if (size<=15).. spaghetti where you perform unnecessary checks on the lower bound.

Also What is the point of fprinting into stderr followed by perror("") ? Just more clutter into the code. perror alone is designed to print your own message along with the actual error information.

"free but has copyright for commercial usage" - if you did not intend to make it available under CC-BY-SA 4.0, you should probably take it down

@EugeneSh. They were suggested by answering of debian and stackoverflow users and I think they are meaningful and these are not unnecessary checks .... for compression they are needed . Depending on file size , root grows ......

@EugeneSh.: Re “if (size == -1) - this can never happen”: That comparison can evaluate as true, and it will when ftell returns its error indication. You can criticize its style, and I would have used a different type for size, but it is not incorrect in regard to whether the code functions as desired.

@HadiLovelorn, Pedantic: input[strlen (input) - 1] = '\0'; is undefined behavior (UB) when the first character read is a null character '\0'.  Use strcspn().

@HadiLovelorn With "everyone said I must check every reading and writing functions . This is the whole program ...", --> why does code not check the return value of fgets() calls?

else if((size>10000000)&&(100000000)) As already mentioned above, you can remove all the checks size > xyz because that must always be true when you enter the else branch. Also, in that specific line, you forgot the size <= for the upper bound. You will never reach the final else branch with that typo.

@chux it finds the length of string and before the last character puts a NULL because fgets takes break line as a character and I edited post , Now checks for fgets too

@Gerhardh It is necessary to find the appropriate root of file by size . And the compiler warning is weird ... May be because of GMP's mpz_root it warns . But if s and else if s and else are necessary and logical

@HadiLovelorn When fgets() returns NULL due to end-of-file, input[] is not assigned and strlen (input) is undefined behaviors (UB) on the first call.  When fgets() returns NULL due to input error,  input[] is indeterminant and strlen (input) risks UB.  Code should not attempt strlen(input) (as done in r1 = fgets(input, 200, stdin);  input[strlen (input) - 1] = '\0';) when fgets() returns NULL.  I don't this is the key issue you have, yet post here lacks input used and output seen.

You didn't get my point. In the line else if((size>10000000)&&(100000000)) the part (size>10000000) is redundant. You will never get to that line if this is not true. Because then the previous condition (size<=10000000) must be true. It is sufficient to check for the next larger upper limit if you keep the checks in ascending order.

@chux Compile and Link for Yourself :  FILE * fp;
char str[200];
fp = fopen("testfile.txt", "w");
fgets(str, 200, stdin);
str[strlen (str) - 1] = '\0';
fprintf(fp, "%s", str);
fclose(fp);
There's no warning or error and it works truly

@HadiLovelorn Your code sample indeed works with select input yet encounters undefined behavior (UB)  when 1) first charter read is a null character 2) stdin is closed (e.g. feof(stdin) returns non-zero 3) fgets() encounters an input error.

@chux I edited the code . Thanks ... The former trick works but is risky , This trick is better

Please do not change the code in your question. It makes comments and/or answers useless. Your question should not be a moving target.

Perhaps this issue?
Code should return when fw == NULL.
    fw = fopen(output, "ab");
    if (fw == NULL)
        printf("File can't be written\n'");

        // I'd expect code to `return 1;` when `fw == NULL`
        // and not go on to do `ferror(fw)`
   
    if (ferror(fw))
    {
    
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during writing to file %s\n", output);
        perror("");
        fclose(fw);
        return 1;
        
    }


Thanks , I edited code . But files were read successfully But I added them too
